# Ethernet and wireless connection problems

Tags: installation, wireless, drivers, ethernet

I am unable get wireless or ethernet connection to work at all.

I have tried many things like trying to download the drivers while booting from the installation disc, and so forth, because this was the only time my laptop would pick up ethernet.

Inevitably this never worked because as soon as I booted without disc I was, once again, back to having no connections at all! I am unable pick up any connection whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was simple enough and anyone with an android phone or any device that supports USB Tethering.. i think will benefit from this.

(This should work as long as your device can currently connect to your wifi)

Simply download USB Tethering app to your device and connect it to your laptop, this will share the connection and give you a wired connection (it did for me)

then you should be able to run the following commands in terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T
then typing:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

I hope this helps